# How do I modify the DB from Flask without posting?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

I have a small *Flask* application that displays a number of items held in an *SQLite 3* database. I also have a *cron* job that runs every day and (should) insert new entries into this database.

I have created the following function to modify the database:

```
def add_entry(name):
    statement = 'insert ....'
    g.db.execute(statement, [name])
    g.db.commit()
```

However, when I run it I receive:

```
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

How do I modify the database without posting to a URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create an application context yourself as explained in the [Flask documentation on this subject](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/appcontext/). Something like

```
with app.app_context():
    add_entry()
```

should do the trick.