# Python using another module to get data from mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-connector, connection

I have 2 py files. `database.py` and `myapp.py`. From `myapp.py`, i want to call `database.py` to create the connection, and perform a mysql query but I do not want the connection to the database to be closed as I need to reuse it. Here's my code.

Can anyone give me some advice ?

**database.py**

```
import mysql.connector
from flask import g

def connect_db():
    return mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password', database='test')

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        #db = g._database = connect_to_database()
        db = g._database = connect_db()
    return db    

def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
```

**myapp.py**

```
from flask import g
from database import connect_db, query_db

for user in query_db('select * from users'):
    print(user['userid'], 'has the password', user['password'])
```

Here's the full trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    for user in query_db('select * from users'):
  File "/root/projects/test2/database.py", line 15, in query_db
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
  File "/root/projects/test2/database.py", line 8, in get_db
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 27, in _lookup_app_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

Comment: you made a lot of copy/paste from code you seem to not understand and led you to those error. May be you should [read again flask doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) slowly and try to use SQLite at first and once it will be ok switch to MySQL

Comment: Hi...Can you help to take a look at this code again ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an application context for your query_db function. See also:
[How do I modify the DB from Flask without posting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304413/how-do-i-modify-the-db-from-flask-without-posting)